# JSF + PrimeFaces returns blank page

Tags: jsf, primefaces, jsf-2

I'm new in JSF and PrimeFaces

so this is my fields.xhtml

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="field" value="#{fieldController.getFields()}">
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.field_id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Label">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.lable}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Type">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.type}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Required">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.required}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Is Active">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.isActive}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```

And this is FieldController

```
@ManagedBean(name = "fieldController", eager = true)
public class FieldController {

@ManagedProperty("#{fileDAO}")
private FieldDAO fieldDAO;

public FieldDAO getFieldDAO() {
    return fieldDAO;
}

public void setFieldDAO(FieldDAO fieldDAO) {
    this.fieldDAO = fieldDAO;
}

public List<Field> getFields() throws Exception{
    return fieldDAO.getFields();
}

}
```

And in the end I see only blank white page.
Help me find where is my problem please.

Comment: is there any exception in the server logs?

Comment: There are no exceptions. Hibernate gets data from db. There is Fields in logs. Also the data comes even to the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test with below code. Primefaces automatically call the getter method. You have to just set the field name. As in your example their in only getter method use method name without get **(#{fieldController.fields}**)

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">
<h:body>
<h:form>
    <p:dataTable var="field" value="#{fieldController.fields}">
        <p:column headerText="Id">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.field_id}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Label">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.lable}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Type">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.type}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Required">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.required}" />
        </p:column>

        <p:column headerText="Is Active">
            <h:outputText value="#{field.isActive}" />
        </p:column>
    </p:dataTable>
</h:form>
</h:body>
</html>
```